# Any patent issue if I want to call my classes "signal/slot" as in Qt?

Tags: licensing, software-patent

I need to code a signal-like mechanism and I was thinking of using the same "slot" and "signal" terms to indicate the signal and the function that needs to be called.

Since this is a commercial application I'd like to know if there might be any issue with using these names, e.g. if Qt has some sort of patent on them (I searched around but couldn't find it).

I believe this is a stupid question since patenting a class name would be moronic, to say the least.. but anyway...

To add some detail: my code is ENTIRELY different and has NOTHING TO DO with Qt except the above. I don't use moc or any Qt class.

Comment: *Names* shouldn't fall under patent law, at most it's a trademark. Then again, considering the current state of the patent system...

Comment: Others have used the signal/slot terms in various libraries (some as alternative options to Qt that are more lightweight). Si it seems that they are nor suing anybody about it.

Comment: kinda hard when Qt isn't the only thing that calls it that (see boost's [signals2 lib](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the terms "signal" and "slot" for a communication mechanism that works completely different from QT's signal/slot mechanism will not get you into conflict with any patents that might exist on the Qt mechanism.

Patents work by protecting an idea, regardless of how that idea is called. To give an example<sup>1</sup>, the inventors of the `foreach` loop could have applied for a patent for "a looping construct that iterates over all elements of a container, without the need for the programmer to keep track if there are more elements." This patent would apply to the `foreach` construct found in many languages, but also to the range-based `for` loop in C++, even though that uses a different keyword.

The only legal protection that exists for simple names is trademark protection. This also doesn't apply in this case, because Qt doesn't use the terms 'signal' and 'slot' as trademarks.

<sup>1: To my knowledge, no such patent exists or at the very least it isn't being enforced. Otherwise there wouldn't be so many languages with this construct.</sup>

Comment: I doubt `foreach` would be patentable, as it is basically a mathematical symbol ("for all", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols).

Comment: @miraculixx: With software patents you never know, but it is moot anyway. I used `foreach` mostly as an example how patents aren't tied to how you call it.